# Why does this update throw an error even though the Alter Table command should be finished?

Tags: sql-server

This has been a nagging issue for me for some time and I would love to know the reason why these SQL Batch commands aren't working.

I have a table that I use to hold configuration settings for a system. When a new setting is added, we add a new field to the table.  During an update, I need to change a slew of databases on the server with the same script.  Generally, they are all in the same state and I can just do the following:

```
Alter Table Configuration Add ShowClassesInCheckin bit;
GO

Update Configuration Set ShowClassesInCheckin=ShowFacilitiesInCheckin;
GO
```

This works fine.  However, sometimes one or two databases get updated so I want to write conditional logic to make these changes only if the field doesn't already exist:

```
if Not Exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'ShowClassesInCheckin' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Configuration'))
BEGIN
    Alter Table Configuration Add ShowClassesInCheckin bit;
    Update Configuration Set ShowClassesInCheckin=ShowFacilitiesInCheckin;
END;
GO
```

In this case, I get an error: "Invalid column name 'ShowClassesInCheckin'"  Now, this makes sense in that the Alter Table isn't comitted in the batch before the Update is called (it doesn't work without the "GO" between the Alter and Update).  But that doesn't help...I still don't know how to I achieve what I am after...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire SQL script is parsed before it's executed.  During the parsing phase, the column will not exist, so the parser generates an error.  The error is raised before the first line of the script is executed.

The solution is dynamic SQL:

```
exec (N'Update Configuration Set ShowClassesInCheckin=ShowFacilitiesInCheckin;')
```

This won't get parsed before the `exec` is reached, and by then, the column will exist.

Comment: Thaaaaat is it!  And you know, it makes perfect sense.  Sometimes you just need to hear it from someone to recognize the obvious answer...  Thanks!

Comment: I find that answers are always so obvious once someone says them. :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that should work is to re-introduce the go.  This means that you need to use something else as the condition for the update, possibly based on database name.

```
if Not Exists(select * from sys.columns where Name = N'ShowClassesInCheckin' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Configuration'))
BEGIN
    Alter Table Configuration Add ShowClassesInCheckin bit;
END;
GO

if *new condition here*
BEGIN
    Update Configuration Set ShowClassesInCheckin=ShowFacilitiesInCheckin;
END;
GO
```

Comment: ummm...but the first item would eliminate the condition that I need to test to figure out whether the second item should be run.  And I can't test whether the field is there because, if so, the user may have set it to a value they want to use that is different from the default.  Thanks anyway though...